# Erlang and run-time record limitations

Tags: erlang, runtime

I'm developing an Erlang system and having reoccurring problems with the fact that records are compile-time pre-processor macros (almost), and that they cant be manipulated at runtime... 
basically, I'm working with a property pattern, where properties are added at run-time to objects on the front-end (AS3). Ideally, I would reflect this with a list on the Erlang side, since its a fundamental data type, but then using records in QCL [to query ETS tables] would not be possible since to use them I have to specifically say which record property I want to query over... I have at least 15 columns in the larges table, so listing them all in one huge switch statement (case X of) is just plain ugly.

does anyone have any ideas how to elegantly solve this? maybe some built-in functions for creating tuples with appropriate signatures for use in pattern matching (for QLC)?

thanks

Comment: It'd help if you give a psuedo-code example of what you'd like to be able to do.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to be able to do something like `get_record_field(Field, SomeRecord)` where `Field` is determined at runtime by user interface code say.

You're right in that you can't do this in standard erlang as records and the `record_info` function are expanded and eliminated at compile time.

There are a couple of solutions that I've used or looked at. My solution is as follows: (the example gives runtime access to the `#dns_rec` and `#dns_rr` records from `inet_dns.hrl`)

```
%% Retrieves the value stored in the record Rec in field Field.
info(Field, Rec) ->
    Fields = fields(Rec),
    info(Field, Fields, tl(tuple_to_list(Rec))).

info(_Field, _Fields, []) -> erlang:error(bad_record);
info(_Field, [], _Rec) -> erlang:error(bad_field);
info(Field, [Field | _], [Val | _]) -> Val;
info(Field, [_Other | Fields], [_Val | Values]) -> info(Field, Fields, Values).

%% The fields function provides the list of field positions
%% for all the kinds of record you want to be able to query
%% at runtime. You'll need to modify this to use your own records.
fields(#dns_rec{}) -> fields(dns_rec);
fields(dns_rec) -> record_info(fields, dns_rec);
fields(#dns_rr{}) -> fields(dns_rr);
fields(dns_rr) -> record_info(fields, dns_rr).

%% Turns a record into a proplist suitable for use with the proplists module.
to_proplist(R) ->
    Keys = fields(R),
    Values = tl(tuple_to_list(R)),
    lists:zip(Keys,Values).
```

A version of this that compiles is available here: [rec_test.erl](http://gist.github.com/71050)

---

You can also extend this dynamic field lookup to dynamic generation of matchspecs for use with `ets:select/2` or `mnesia:select/2` as shown below:

```
%% Generates a matchspec that does something like this
%% QLC psuedocode: [ V || #RecordKind{MatchField=V} <- mnesia:table(RecordKind) ]
match(MatchField, RecordKind) ->
    MatchTuple = match_tuple(MatchField, RecordKind),
    {MatchTuple, [], ['$1']}.

%% Generates a matchspec that does something like this
%% QLC psuedocode: [ T || T <- mnesia:table(RecordKind),
%%                        T#RecordKind.Field =:= MatchValue]
match(MatchField, MatchValue, RecordKind) ->
    MatchTuple = match_tuple(MatchField, RecordKind),
    {MatchTuple, [{'=:=', '$1', MatchValue}], ['$$']}.

%% Generates a matchspec that does something like this
%% QLC psuedocode: [ T#RecordKind.ReturnField
%%                   || T <- mnesia:table(RecordKind),
%%                        T#RecordKind.MatchField =:= MatchValue]
match(MatchField, MatchValue, RecordKind, ReturnField) 
  when MatchField =/= ReturnField ->
    MatchTuple = list_to_tuple([RecordKind
           | [if F =:= MatchField -> '$1'; F =:= ReturnField -> '$2'; true -> '_' end
              || F <- fields(RecordKind)]]),
    {MatchTuple, [{'=:=', '$1', MatchValue}], ['$2']}.


match_tuple(MatchField, RecordKind) ->
    list_to_tuple([RecordKind
           | [if F =:= MatchField -> '$1'; true -> '_' end
              || F <- fields(RecordKind)]]).
```

---

Ulf Wiger has also written a parse_transform, [Exprecs](http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=21790), that more or less does this for you automagically. I've never tried it, but Ulf's code is usually very good.

---

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem (in development) by use the parse transform tools to read the .hrl files and generate helper functions.

I wrote a [tutorial](http://trapexit.org/Match_Specifications_And_Records_(Dynamically!)) on it at [Trap Exit](http://trapexit.org/).

We use it all the time to generate match specs. The beauty is that you don't need to know anything about the current state of the record *at development time*.

However once you are in production things change! If your record is the basis of a table (as opposed to the definition of a field in a table) then changing an underlying record is  more difficult (to put it mildly!).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your Problem but I have moved from records to [proplists](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/lib/stdlib-1.11.0/doc/html/proplists.html) in most cases. They are much more flexible and much slower. Using (d)ets I usually use a few record fields for coarse selection and then check the proplists on the remaining records for detailed selection.

Comment: Proplists are handy if you never need to pattern-match them (my main use is options lists as `proplists:get_value/3` allows you to retrieve a value or use a default in one operation.

If you ever want to pattern match however, you need records for named slot access.